# TortoiseSVN on Windows Server 2008 - Error Option 200 when checking out

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have recently setup a repository on one of my servers with TortoiseSVN.

I have created a repository in the following directory:

```
/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dev
```

On my local machine, when I try to check out this repository from the following URL, which I put in the **URL of Repository**, I get the following message.

```
http://the.path.tomyserver:21133/Dev/
```

The reason for the port number is because it is running on a virtual instance, and port identification is required for access to the instance.

I am getting the following error:

```
Error OPTIONS of 'http://the.path.tomyserver:21133/Dev/: 200 OK(http://the.path.tomyserver:21133)
```

It doesn't tell me anything additional.

I am lost on what to do next.

Comment: Is your server configured to host Subversion? If you create a Subversion repository on a server, the web server has to be configured that the repository is really hosted. If you have the possibility to access the directory on the server directly, you could instead use a file-URL for that. See ["Adressing the Repository"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.reposurls) for the different options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem, it turns out I did not have the web server actually configured to run Subversion even though I was running the service.

This turned out to be the first problem which was corrected by accessing the repository using the following path:

svn://the.path.tomyserver/dev

Additionally, my webserver was not configured to allow port 3699 through which is the default used by Subversion.

Once I opened this port, I was able to successfully checkout my repository.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if the server isn't set up correctly. Either WebDAV isn't configured or the location does not point to an SVN repository - either way, the WebDAV response to an OPTIONS request must not be "200".